# Non-child divs not taking 100% of the screen, but one does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently got a Ubuntu server to start running a web server, so I'm building a page to populate it. I ran into some awkward div behavior recently though, and I can't find any documentation or anything to explain it. I have 4 separate non-child divs that are hidden off screen to the left, and the first one seems to take the 100% height property correctly, while the others seems to just not. I tried to make the divs different lengths off screen to no avail. I suspect this problem to be some faulty css, but it could potentially be tied to the JQuery as well. Also, the empty conditions in the css are parts of the wesite I haven't gotten around to making pretty yet.

Material can be found here for tinkering as needed: https://codepen.io/ClaytonSchrumpf/pen/zmepwy

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "../css/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Clayton Schrumpf</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainContent">
        <div id="header">
            <h1 id="name">Clayton Schrumpf</h1>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div id="aboutMeContainer">
            <button class="linkStart" id="aboutMe">About Me</button>
        </div>    
        <div id="resumeContainer">
            <button class="linkStart" id="resume">My Resume</button>
        </div>
        <div id="pastProjectsContainer">
            <button class="linkStart" id="pastProjects">Past Projects</button>
        </div>
        <div id="contactContainer">
            <button class="linkStart" id="contact">Contact Me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subpage" id="aboutMePage">
        <button class="back">Back</button>
    </div>
    <div class="subpage" id="resumePage">
        <button class="back">Back</button>
    </div>
    <div class="subpage" id="pastProjectsPage">
        <button class="back">Back</button>
    </div>
    <div class="subpage" id="contactPage">
        <button class="back">Back</button>
    </div>  
    <script src="../js/buttonMove.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body{
    width:100%;
    height=100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}

#mainContent{
    width:100%;
    height=100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:rgb(225, 225, 225, 225);
    color:#000000;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas:
        ". gHead gHead ."
        "gButton1 gButton1 gButton1 gButton1"
        "gButton2 gButton2 gButton2 gButton2"
        "gButton3 gButton3 gButton3 gButton3"
        "gButton4 gButton4 gButton4 gButton4";
}

.back{
     background:none;
    color: #000000;
    padding:0!important;
    font:inherit;
    position: relative;
    margin-top:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: 0px!important;
    font-size:4vmin;
    float: right;
    margin-right:2vmin;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.linkStart{
    background:none;
    color: #000000;
    padding:0!important;
    font:inherit;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: 0px!important;
    font-size:4vmin;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    border:solid black;
}

#name{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:8vmin
}

#header{
    grid-area:gHead;
    align-self:center;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

#aboutMeContainer{
    grid-area: gButton1;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 2;
    border:1px solid;
}
#aboutMe{
    background:rgba(200, 172 , 178);
}

#resumeContainer{
    grid-area:gButton2;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid;
}
#resume{

}

#pastProjectsContainer{
    grid-area: gButton3;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid;

}
#pastProjects{
    background:rgba(161, 172, 200);
}

#contactContainer{
    grid-area: gButton4;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid;

}
#contact{
}

.subpage{
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    position:relative;
    background-color:rgb(200,172,178);
    height:100%;
    width:1px;
    left:-1vmin;
}
#aboutMePage{

}

#resumePage{

}

#pastProjectsPage{

}

#contactPage{

}
```

JS with JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedBut;
    var selectedDiv;

     $(".linkStart").click(function(event) {
            $(this).animate({left: "+=100%"}, 750);
             selectedBut = (event.target.id);
             if(selectedBut === "aboutMe"){
                 selectedDiv = "#aboutMePage";
                 selectedBut = "#aboutMe";
             } else if(selectedBut === "resume"){
                 selectedDiv = "#resumePage";
                 selectedBut = "#resume";
             } else if(selectedBut === "pastProjects") {
                 selectedDiv = "#pastProjectsPage";
                 selectedBut = "#pastProjects";
             } else if(selectedBut === "contact"){
                 selectedDiv = "#contactPage";
                 selectedBut = "#contact"
             }
             $(selectedDiv).css("left", "1vmin")
             $(selectedDiv).animate({"width":"100%"},  750);

         });

         $(".back").click(function() {
            $(selectedDiv).animate({"width":"1px"});
            $(selectedBut).animate({left:"-=100%"});
             $(selectedDiv).css("left", "-1vmin");
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For anyone who ever has this problem too, you want the hidden divs to have a position of absolute. Else they just stack one after another down the page.